# Reset or clear Lucene indexing

Tags: java, hibernate, lucene, hibernate-search

At the moment I'm in the proces of writing unit tests for my lucene queries. Therefor I create a test-database containing dummy data. For each test I recreate my database, so each test is started using "fresh" data. Normally I just put my hbm
ddl property to create(as shown below)

```
<property name="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto">update</property>
```

But I noticed that this doesn't clear the Lucene indexes. Anyone got an idea how I can make sure that each test is run on a freshly created index? My temporary solution is a script the runs before each test, that will simple delete the indexing folders. But since these folders are somewhere on the file system, I hoped there was a more generic/standard approach to this... any ideas?

Answer (score 4):

You can create new [IndexWriter](http://lucene.apache.org/core/old_versioned_docs/versions/3_0_1/api/core/org/apache/lucene/index/IndexWriter.html#IndexWriter%28org.apache.lucene.store.Directory,%20org.apache.lucene.analysis.Analyzer,%20boolean,%20org.apache.lucene.index.IndexDeletionPolicy,%20org.apache.lucene.index.IndexWriter.MaxFieldLength%29) by setting **create=true**. This will override the existing index.

Comment: Thx, Is it possible to define and configure the IndexWriter in hibernate.cfg.xml?

Comment: Check the part 3.6 in this document : http://tinyurl.com/c6yloaj . Hope it will help.